# Hover stops working when applied to child div and buttons disappear when position set to absolute

Tags: html, css, hover, position

Here is a relatively newbie question about why hovering doesn't work on child element and also why an element disappears when I change their position to "absolute".

My project is basic and has a header, a footer and a container. In the container there is a child div called "imagewrap" that has an image. I want to add some buttons that allow you to change the image. And I want those buttons to appear when you hover over the image, as you can see in this gif,

[image]

the buttons do appear when I hover over the container, but they do below the image. If I change their position to absolute:

```
.buttons {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}
```

They disappear. I also have no idea why.

Here is the code for html and css:

css

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
}

#imagewrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 430px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#controllers {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
}

#container #imagewrap:hover .buttons {
opacity: 1;
}

.buttons {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}

#previous {
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url(Images/carremoins.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 4;
}

#next {
    background-image: url(Images/carreplus.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 4;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

html

```
<body>

    <div id="header">
    </div>

      <div id="container">

        <div id="imagewrap">
          <img src="Images/01PARANA/Image.jpg" height="500px" id="front" />

          <div id="previous" class="buttons" onclick="change(-1);">
          </div>

          <div id="next" class="buttons" onclick="change(1);">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    <div id="footer">
    </div>

    </body>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this selector for the hovering:

```
#imagewrap > img:hover ~ .buttons { ... }
```

That's a general sibling selector - the image is a sibling to the button elements.

Concerning the not-visible buttons: Do change their `position` to `absolute` - there is no other way to place them inside the image. You need to give them width/height values (otherwise they'll be 0x0) and also position (if you don't want them in the upper left corner), for example `bottom: 10px;` and `left: 10px` / `right: 10px`